# How to enter php value in html?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>
```

This above code is use to get the page url..
Now i want to result from above code in a html code..

```
<?php
$r .= '<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments href="I WANT THE ANSWER IN HERE" num_posts="2" width="400"></fb:comments>';
?>
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php

$r = '<div id="fb-root"></div>'. PHP_EOL;
$r .='<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>'. PHP_EOL;
$r .='<fb:comments href="'.curPageURL().'" num_posts="2" width="400"></fb:comments>'. PHP_EOL;

echo $r;

?>
```

`PHP_EOL;` ensures a line break in your document (makes it more readable, if you click **view source**).

Comment: Added a little extra (PHP_EOL). Pleased to have been able to help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the additional `<?php` `?>` tags in your output Also you have a space between the opening `<?` and the php keyword... which would throw an error. Try this code below, note I haven't checked on my own server but it looks right.

```
<?php
$r .= '<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments href="'.$pageURL.'" num_posts="2" width="400"></fb:comments>';
?>
```

Comment: no it shouldn't because you're setting a variable. notice how I removed the single quotes and added in the variable result again.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to call your function first and store the result of it inside a variable. You can than use that variable in your html.

Example:

```
<?php
$result = curPageUrl();
?>

<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments href="<?php echo $result; ?>" num_posts="2" width="400"></fb:comments>
```

**Edit**

You could simplify it by staying in HTML the majority of the time and only break into php to output your curPageUrl().

Example:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments href="<?php echo curPageUrl(); ?>" num_posts="2" width="400"></fb:comments>
```

Comment: i did that but not working...i think its becourse html code is inside the php code..do u have another way ?

Comment: @Navi, I edited my original answer with an alternate method you can try. You stay in HTML for most of it and then only break into PHP when you need to call your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
<?php
$r .= '<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments href="'.curPageURL().'" num_posts="2" width="400"></fb:comments>';

//echo $r;

?>
```